# SAS Retain Specific Variable for Later Use

Tags: sas

I am attempting to calculate a series of values each based on the one after it.  For example, variable A in row 10 is used to calculate variable B in row 9, variable A in row 10 and variable B in row 9 is used to calculate variable C in row 8, etc.  Is there a good way to do this?  Each row has a character variable/name that labels it.  I've attempted the retain statement with this code, but isn't retaining that specific value:

```
data null;
set oldData;
if name = 'Jimmy' then do;
    variableA = variableNull1 + variableNull2;
    retain variableA;
end;
if name = 'Johnny' then do;
    variableB = variable A + variableNull3;
    retain variableB;
end;
if name = 'Bobby' then do;
    variableC = variableA + variable B + variableNull4;
    retain variableC;
end;
(continue process for a few more lines)
run;
```

Another idea is if I could easily fill up and down for each variable that would work also.  Thank you all for the help.

The desired output is:

```
Jimmy     VariableNull3                                 VariableC
Johnny    VariableNull2                   VariableB
Bobby     VariableNull1     VariableA
```

Note that the null variables are generic and there could be multiple.  It is also okay if we had output like this (but the first is preferred):

```
Jimmy     VariableNull3     VariableA      VariableB           VariableC
Johnny    VariableNull2     VariableA      VariableB           VariableC
Bobby     VariableNull1     VariableA      VariableB           VariableC
```

Comment: Can you post the input dataset and desired output sample?

Comment: @NeOmen I just added two outputs that would be okay with me.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the sample input as well?

Comment: I think you should calculate variable A B C seperately.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide sample data to clarify what exactly you are after.

```
/* fake data */
data sample;
do i = 1 to 10;
VariableNULL1 = rand("Uniform");
VariableNULL2 = VariableNULL1 * 1.02;
VariableNULL3 = 0.55 * VariableNULL2 + 0.35;
VariableNULL4 = VariableNULL3 + 0.2;
output;
end;
drop i;
run;

/* Everytime you get VarA first, then based on that you have VarB and so on. Retain statement will keep the previous record */
data sample2;
set sample;
/* retain previous values */
retain prev1-prev2;
VariableA = sum(of VariableNULL1-VariableNULL2); /* VarA is based on VarNULLs */
VariableB = prev1 + VariableNULL3; /* VarB is derived from previous VarA */
VariableC = prev2 + VariableNULL3 + VariableNULL4; 
prev2 = prev1; 
prev1 = VariableA; 
drop prev:; /* it will be more clear to you if you keep prev1 & prev2 in output dataset. It shows how SAS calculate VarB and VarC */
run;
```

Comment: Please post more than just code in an answer - in fact, non-code explanations are _more_ important than code.  Explain how your solution solves the problem, so we are teaching programmers to fish, not simply giving them a fish.